# SQL Sybase ASE - select most recent date and max price

Tags: sql, max, sybase, partitioning, sap-ase

I am working on **Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 25127 SMP SP136 /P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/ase157sp136x/3955/64-bit/FBO/Mon Oct 19 19:12:00 2015**

I have a table that includes records with multiple dates and prices, and I am looking to select the most recent date AND the price that is the highest or max.

For error messages, the **max()** function doesn't seem to work and just returns hundreds of thousands of records. When I try **Row_number()** or **Rank() OVER (Partition by columnname order by columnname)** I receive a syntax error near **OVER is incorrect**. Upon reading other threads, it looks like this is not available in Sybase ASE.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Example of one record in table:

```
ID     TRADE_DATE  TRADE_PRICE
B52A   05/12/2016  91
B52A   05/13/2016  85
B52A   05/13/2016  86
B52A   05/16/2016  85
B52A   05/16/2016  90
```

Expected Output (just one row per record, no duplicates):

```
ID     TRADE_DATE  TRADE_PRICE
B52A   05/16/2016  90
```

My code:

```
SELECT T1.ID
FROM T1

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
  T2.ID,
  T2.TRADE_DATE,
  T2.TRADE_PRICE
FROM T2
WHERE ID='B52A')
ON T2.ID=T1.ID
```

Also, if I try doing:

```
SELECT
ID,
MAX(TRADE_DATE),
MAX(TRADE PRICE)

FROM T2
WHERE ID ='B52A'

GROUP BY
  ID
ORDER BY
  ID
  TRADE_DATE
  TRADE_PRICE
```

It selects the correct record, but it repeats it 5 times:

```
ID     TRADE_DATE  TRADE_PRICE
B52A   05/16/2016  90
B52A   05/16/2016  90
B52A   05/16/2016  90
B52A   05/16/2016  90
B52A   05/16/2016  90
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the OVER syntax since the SAP/Sybase ASE database does not support it.

You need to write the SQL code manually. One example is:

```
SELECT
  T1.ID, x.max_TRADE_DATE, max(TRADE_PRICE) AS max_TRADE_PRICE
FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, MAX(TRADE_DATE) AS max_TRADE_DATE
  FROM T1 GROUP BY ID
) x 
JOIN
  T1 on T1.ID = x.ID and T1.TRADE_DATE = x.max_TRADE_DATE
GROUP BY
  T1.ID, x.max_TRADE_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct * FROM (SELECT
ID,
MAX(TRADE_DATE) trade_date,
MAX(TRADE PRICE) trade_price

FROM T2
WHERE ID ='B52A'

GROUP BY
  ID
)
ORDER BY
  ID,
  TRADE_DATE,
  TRADE_PRICE
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.